# Does psexec allow a service to be installed from a remote location?

Tags: service, msbuild, psexec

I have an msbuild script that installs a service on my DEV environment using psexec. This all works fine. Now that I want to run it against UAT, where instead of the service exe being located on a shared folder on the app server, it's located on the NAS/a network folder, I get an error.

Is this possible to achieve using psexec?

The following works:

```
psexec.exe \\my-app-server -u DOMAIN\MyServiceAccount -p MyServiceAccountPassword \\my-app-server\MyShare\MyService.exe install /instance:DEV
```

But this doesn't work:

```
psexec.exe \\my-app-server -u DOMAIN\MyServiceAccount -p MyServiceAccountPassword \\my-NAS\MyShare\MyService.exe install /instance:UAT1
```

I get the error

```
PsExec could not start \\my-NAS\MyShare\MyService.exe on my-app-server:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Here is the msbuild script generating the above:

```
<Exec Command="psexec \\$(TargetServer) -u $(ServiceAccountUn) -p $(ServiceAccountPw)  $(TargetServiceInstallPath) install /instance:$(Environment)"/>
```

I have tried running psexec direct from the command line as well, so I guess msbuild doesn't really have anything to do with the problem, as this gives the same result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that this is not possible.

Comment: This isn't really an answer - did you try the offered solution from Samer Adra?

Comment: @Jonathon Samer's answer wasn't applicable because it didn't explain why the install worked depending on the location of the source file (and yes I tried it anyway). According to a sysadmin I spoke to, psexec just isn't compatible with UNC folder names.

Answer (score 0):

The exe/dll files have to be there before you try to install them. psexec has a -c flag to copy over the application you're trying to run.